# How to set a global connection string for all crystal reports in my project (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a VB.Net project with SQL Server DB. I want to add few Crystal reports to it. I'm using a connection string inside a module which i use every where in my project and its very useful since i can change the login details at a single point.

```
connString As String = "Data Source=192.168.1.11,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=MY_DB;User Id=sa;Password = abc@1234.;" 'global connection string
```

Same way, is it possible to have a common global connection string somewhere embedded inside (Ex. module) my project (Not a DSN) or is possible to use the above conn string.

If it's possible, what is the correct method of doing it and i would be grateful, if someone can post a sample code.

Comment: Connection strings often find their place in `app.config`. See also [Connection String Builders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-builders)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public connString As String = "Data Source=192.168.1.11,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=MY_DB;User Id=sa;Password = abc@1234.;"
```

By declaring Public, you can use `connstring` anywhere in your project.

Comment: Sorry for asking something as simple as this. Im little new to crystal reports. When i add a cry rep to my project, the window i get to add the connection does not show my connection string since its in a module. How can i use this conn string for a cry report. Can u post a sample code?